# How to register New Users as Students? (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to learn to use Authentication & Identity Security in MVC and Entity Framework and having some difficulty.

I am working on a University Web App and the issue I am having is connecting the new Users who will be registering in the App as different roles like Students or Instructor. I have created 3 roles already in my Seed method, Admin, Student, and Instructor.

How can I write the `Register` method in the **AccountController** to connect the Student table and the ApplicationUser table?

Or like when a Student logs in, he is only able to see his account, not the list of students in the Students page?

I created a Foreign Key with the **ApplicationUser** table and the **Person** table (Student and Instructor tables inherit from Person table).

```
public abstract class Person
    {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    //Assign Role to User
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin"))
                    .ToList(), "Name", "Name");

                AddErrors(result);
            }

      // Register Student
```

**RegisterViewModel**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserRoles")]
        public string UserRoles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently, a student user can see everyone, but I want the student to see only his account information. Note everyone's info.

[image: Students Page]

**Configuration.cs** (Seed method)

```
protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis",    LastName = "Barzdukas",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan",      LastName = "Li",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy",    LastName = "Justice",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura",    LastName = "Norman",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino",     LastName = "Olivetto",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01") }
            };


            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            //Adding users
            //if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Car"))
            //{
            //    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            //    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            //    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "sampleTwo@email.com", Email = "sampleTwo@email.com" };

            //    manager.Create(user, "password123");
            //}
```

I have googled a lot, but was not able to come up with a customized register method to work with different tables. Any assistance will be much helpful.

Comment: But you are logged in as an admin...that's the expected result, right?

Comment: As an Admin, yeah, it is fine.But when I log in as a Student user, he is also able to do the same and I don't want that.

Comment: Can you log in as Alonso and change the picture in your question?

Comment: the problem in the data that is returned to the view. in the controller filter the results by the user id and if the user is in the role "Admin" don't apply the filter....

Comment: @Hackerman I can create a Alonso User who has a role of a Student, but that is not the same Alonso as the one in Student list. That is one of my main concern. I don't know how to have the same person in both the `ApplicationUser` table and the `Student` table.   I have added my `Seed()` method in my original post.

Comment: i recommend you use the Identity's role table instead u dont even need a FK to your own table

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your SQL hit based on user role.

```
      var whereClause = "";
      if (User.Roll = "Student")
      {
            whereClause = "WHERE USER_NAME = '" + User.Name + "'";
      }
            sqlQuery = "SELECT .... " + whereClause;
```

If the user is not an Admin, only their record will be returned.

Comment: But dont do it like that ;) use parameterised queries... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175852(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Oh I completely agree! Sorry I just wrote it up quick and dirty. I excluded most of the SQL-y syntax out.

Comment: Is there a way where when someone registers as a role of a Student, he gets created in the Student table also?

Comment: In all honesty, you probably don't even what to give them the choice. Make everyone who logs in a student, or teacher? (I don't know how you want to split up roles outside of Admin) Then Allow admins a separate tab to add users to the Admin role/ table as needed.

Comment: To answer your question, all you need is another SQL hit to the student table to update it as well as the Application Users table. You should already have all of the necessary pieces of user data to do so.

Comment: @Ethilium No, when someone registers, he selects the role he is going to register as, like as a Student or Instructor. Then once he is registered, he logs in as his assigned role. And forgive me, but I am pretty new to Entity Framework & SQL. What do you mean by SQL "hit" ?

Comment: richzilla the point is that OPs problem is in how the data is filtered. The question is not "how do I prevent a sql injection" @ethilium is correct OP needs to filter the results for the data that belongs to the student unless the user is in the role admin.

Comment: Sorry, its slang. Basically when you send your update for the Application Users table, send a second update to the Students table based on the role they select. I get really nervous when I allow users to manipulate a database. If I was creating this portal, I would only allow Instructors to add users and set roles. You may be asking too much of students to not set themselves as Admins/Instructors. There is nothing preventing them from adding a secondary account as Admin "Foo Bar" and looking at other users data.

Comment: @Ethilium, true. Didn't think about that. Thank you for the different insight. I am just confused and lost at this point. I will have research more now on like how to create a page for the Admins to manage/approve the roles for the users and how to fix the Students & ApplicationUsers tables.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solution answered your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer.